# Suddenly All Video Players Relying on Python Do Not Work in Precise 12.04 amd64

Tags: video, python, vlc

Until several days ago everything was working fine. Last time I used VLC was may be a week or 2 ago. I first noticed the behaviour when trying to play a mp4 video I had played before without trouble in VLC. Then I got the message:

```
No suitable decoder module:
VLC does not support the audio or video format "h264". Unfortunately
there is no way for you to fix this.
```

Then I successfuly played it with SMPlayer, UMPlayer, gxine, Xine and GNOME MPlayer. However it was not possible to play it in the default Ubuntu Application Movie Player, Banshee Media Player, Dragon Player and VLC Media Player. On all not functioning Players except VLC I was hit by a pop-up window with title:

```
Install extra multimedia plugins?
Python (v2.7) requires to install plugins to play media files of the
following type: H264 decoder

Gstreamer ffmpeg video plugin (i386)
Gstreamer plugins for mms, wavpack, quicktime, musepack (i386)
```

In addition none of those players is able to play any Flash Video format flv ... Without any message nor pop-up. For h264, I still can play the sound but no video.

Trouble is I already have these packages installed in architecture amd64. I don't see why I would have to install plugins for i386 ?

However the common point with all these players is (may be) they use Python. I am sure for VLC that they use Python.

I didn't install anything Python related since those video players worked fine. Only the system updates.

So I don't see what else I can do and why suddenly my Python 2.7 is not working anymore for VLC and other Media Players ?

Has anyone any insights on this quite unheard of situation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. In any Debian or Ubuntu distribution there is a `libopenjpeg2` package. The version installed is (for all Ubuntu distribs) `1.3+dfsg-4.6` . The developer of this package is `http://www.openjpeg.org`. Their Google Code website is at `http://code.google.com/p/openjpeg`. This comes with other packages like `libopenjpeg-dev` and `openjpeg-tools`.

I saw that the version shipping with the distributions was their first release dating back to May 2009. Then I decided to compile and build myself the latest 2.0.0 version (from Nov. 2012). That was working fine. I named my new package `libopenjpeg2.0`. That was fine. Everything was running OK. Then I decided to get rid of the oldest version 1.3 and right after I began to see some applications would not start like `DeVeDe`, `VLC Media Player`, `Banshee Media Player`, `Movie Player` and others ... Some like `DeVeDe` launched from the command line reported the library `libopenjpeg.so.2` as missing.

Re-installing `libopenjpeg v1.3` solved the issue. I learned through this process that the OpenJPEG releases 1.3, 1.5 and 2.0 are not incremental releases of the same stuff. You basically need all of them installed in different package names.

In Debian Unstable I saw the version 1.5 build in package `libopenjpeg5` and had some hints that the 2.0.0 version would be in package `libopenjpeg6`.

Packages for the 1.5 version might be found [here](https://launchpad.net/~otto-kesselgulasch/+archive/gimp-experimental/).